# adding version control Git to my already deployed wp website

Tags: wordpress, github, migrate

I have a wordpress website on hostinger and im trying use version control Git on it without downloading the files locally but i have no idea what to do or where to start ! my goal would be pushing to github as if im working locally (but im not the files are on the server and i dont want to download them ) please Help.

Comment: Let's say that you can create the repository on your site's server (some hosting providers won't provide the tools needed for this so check with Hostinger first) you'd still be downloading all of your site's files and folders to your computer as soon as you do a [git pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), so why are you against of creating the repository on your computer in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
Unfortunately you can not push at once from hostinger to Github.

I have 7 steps for you to push all code to the GIT server:

1)Install github locally
[Download github](https://desktop.github.com/)
2)Copy the files of your website to local directory
3)Open cmd.exe on windows **follow** to your catalog with Website files and run next command to **initialize** new git repository locally

```
git init
```

4)Add files to your locall repo

```
git add .
```

5)Add commit

```
git commit -m "First commit of website"
```

6)Create remote repo link for your website on github.com and copy link to the next command(replace CAPS)

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

7)Push all files to Github

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Is GIT included in GitHub desktop? I think they are two different things. You need to download both GIT from https://git-scm.com/ and then if you wish to use a desktop client, you can download GitHub Desktop. But the latter isn't necessary if you use an editor with a visual GIT interface included.

Comment: Good day. Not sure, but stackoverflow says it has "command line" path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.5\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a git repo for the files on a server and add a GitHub repo as the remote for this. Then you can push files from your Hostinger server to GitHub. To do this, you will ideally need SSH access to your hosting. This seems possible with Hostinger depending on your hosting plan. See [how to login to hostinger account via SSH](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583245-how-can-i-log-in-to-my-account-via-ssh).

Once you've logged into your hosting account via SSH:

1. Change into your website's folder using `cd /path/to/folder`
2. Start a new git repo in this folder using `git init`
3. Add all your existing files using `git add .`
4. Commit the files you've added using `git commit -m "Commit message"`
5. Create a new repo on GitHub (if you haven't already)
6. Add the empty GitHub repo as the remote for the files on your server using `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git`
7. You should now be able to push files to GitHub using `git push origin main` or `git push origin master`